# Registro aleatório da MySQL BD impedindo registros iguais consecutivos

Tags: php, mysql, random

Eu tenho uma base de dados onde eu quero pegar um registro aleatório. Eu consigo fazer isso perfeitamente com:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `mytable` ORDER BY RAND()
```

O problema é que a base de dados contém a ordem de entrada dos registros dos jóqueis na competição e nenhum jóquei pode percorrer o percurso consecutivamente. Eu tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
+----------------+---------+-----+
| jumper         | horse   |  id |
+----------------+---------+------
| Pedro          | gfs     |   1 |
| Gustavo        | psg     |   2 |
| Breno          | sdwed   |   3 |
| bruno          | sdsd    |   4 |
| Carlos         | powkd   |   5 |
| Andrea         | linda   |   6 |
| Gustavo        | handara |   7 |
+----------------+---------+-----+
```

Eu tenho que impedir que o jóquei Gustavo seja sorteado a percorrer o percurso consecutivamente pois ele teria que trocar de cavalos muito rapidamente. De fato, se ele for sorteado, ele só pode ser sorteado de novo depois de três outros competidores. Apreciaria quaisquer ideias em como fazer isso.

Comment: Gustavo, este é o StackOverflow em Português. Favor traduzir sua pergunta.

Comment: @mutlei falta o título...

Comment: @JorgeB. pronto

Comment: Gustavo quer fazer isso só com SQL? ou usando PHP? O que tentou fazer até agora?

Comment: Por que não gerenciar isso direto na aplicação? Podes fazer isso de forma bem mais simples.

Comment: Olá, após sorteio o que faz? Grava numa tabela? Qual? Se não como sabe que já foi sorteado?

Answer (score 1):

Concordo com os comentários que apontam para uma solução via aplicação e não via BD. Mas se quer fazer direto dentro do BD, eu sugiro criar uma coluna nova que vai armazenar algo como SORTEADO! Com isso, você pode usar um WHERE na sua consulta buscando apenas por SORTEADO != TRUE. O problema com esta solução é que você teria que ficar marcando e desmarcando os jóqueis sorteados.

Como não sei a estrutura do seu banco, caso você tenha uma outra tabela com as corridas e seus participantes, também dá pra usar esta informação (ao invés de criar uma coluna nova na tabela de jóqueis). Nesta solução, imagino que seria o caso de fazer um JOIN das tabelas, filtrar fora a última corrida, e pegar aleatoriamente mais N corredores dos que sobraram (usando o LIMIT N). Neste caso, tem que lembrar de usar o DISTINCT(id) para os jóqueis antes de fazer o "sorteio".

Answer (score 1):

Uma das forma é:

Cria uma nova coluna para controle, eu criei uma com o nome "volta"
A query ficou assim:

```
 SELECT * FROM `mytable`
 WHERE volta = 0  
 OR (SELECT COUNT(volta) FROM mytable
 WHERE volta = 1) >= 3
 ORDER BY RAND()
 LIMIT 1;
```

Ai depois na aplicação da um UPDATE mytable SET volta = 1 WHERE id = ?;

Se precisar fazer tudo pelo banco, então vai ser necessário criar uma procedure, ai então você salva o id uma variavel, da o update, e só então retorna o select para a aplicação usando a variavel como filtro

espero ter ajudado, boa sorte!